# AES decryption in Java - IvParameterSpec too big

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I'm going to decrypt a plaintext with two keys.

As you see in the picture we have one encrypted file which contains KEY1 (128 bytes), KEYIV (128 bytes), key2 (128 bytes) - which is not used in this case - and the ciphertext.

[image: descriptive image]

The error I get here is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: 
Wrong IV length: must be 16 bytes long.
```

but it is 64 bytes.

```
public class AES {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  byte[] encKey1 = new byte[128];

  byte[] EncIV = new byte[256];
  byte[] UnEncIV = new byte[128];
  byte[] unCrypKey = new byte[128];
  byte[] unCrypText = new byte[1424];

  File f = new File("C://ftp//ciphertext.enc");
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(F);
  byte[] EncText = new byte[(int) f.length()];
  fis.read(encKey1);
  fis.read(EncIV);
  fis.read(EncText);
  EncIV = Arrays.copyOfRange(EncIV, 128, 256);
  EncText = Arrays.copyOfRange(EncText, 384, EncText.length);
  System.out.println(EncText.length);
  KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
  char[] password = "lab1StorePass".toCharArray();
  java.io.FileInputStream fos = new java.io.FileInputStream(
    "C://ftp//lab1Store");
  ks.load(fos, password);

  char[] passwordkey1 = "lab1KeyPass".toCharArray();

  PrivateKey Lab1EncKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey("lab1EncKeys",
    passwordkey1);

  Cipher rsaDec = Cipher.getInstance("RSA"); // set cipher to RSA decryption
  rsaDec.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, Lab1EncKey); // initalize cipher ti lab1key

  unCrypKey = rsaDec.doFinal(encKey1); // Decryps first key

  UnEncIV = rsaDec.doFinal(EncIV); //decryps encive byte array to undecrypted bytearray---- OBS! Error this is 64 BYTES big, we want 16?
  System.out.println("lab1key "+ unCrypKey +" IV " + UnEncIV);
  //-------CIPHERTEXT decryption---------
  Cipher AESDec = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
  //---------convert decrypted bytearrays to acctual keys
  SecretKeySpec unCrypKey1 = new SecretKeySpec(unCrypKey, "AES");
  IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(UnEncIV);

  AESDec.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, unCrypKey1, ivSpec );

  unCrypText = AESDec.doFinal(EncText);

  // Convert decrypted cipher bytearray to string
  String deCryptedString = new String(unCrypKey);
  System.out.println(deCryptedString);
 }
```

Comment: So, what are you struggling with? The errormessage could not be more precise ... For using the algorithm you have to provide an IV with 16 bytes length instead of 64. SO the first step has to be if your RSA-Decryption of the IV is correct.

Comment: As an aside, it is not necessary to encrypt the IV, only the key.  You can send the IV in clear if that is easier for you.

Comment: @Fildor or, if you want it to be maintainable, the IV should be identical to Cipher.getBlockSize(), which in the case of AES/CBC will be 16.

Comment: We cannot determine what goes wrong without knowing how the encrypted file was created. If you indeed supplied 64 bytes to the PKCS#1 algorithm then this is what you can expect, and the error message is precise, as Fildor mused. If you did not provide 64 bytes then we need more data. If unsure, you could use "RSA/ECB/NoPadding" to see what has been encrypted, but that's advanced debugging I suppose.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is that he's confusing bits and bytes. Looks at the definitions and range he copies.

Answer (score 2):

Your arrays are completely wrong because of confusion between bits and bytes. Your IV is actually 256 bytes long, not 64, and even if the application got past that, it would complain about the 128 byte key. AES is a 128 bit cipher that uses a 128 bit to 256 *bit* key. It should all look more like this:

```
byte[] encKey1 = new byte[16];
byte[] EncIV = new byte[16];
byte[] UnEncIV = new byte[16];
byte[] unCrypKey = new byte[16];
```

Another potential error is the definition of unCrypText, which should be:

```
byte[] unCrypText = new byte[(int) f.length()];
```

just like EncText, but that might not matter for testing.

Comment: I'm afraid that is just the start of his worries, e.g. the `unCryptText` array is never actually used. To differentiate between bits and bytes for keys I normally use e.g. `128 / Byte.SIZE` which clearly shows what is intended. For the IV you can use `Cipher.getBlockSize()`.